# How to increase size of text in Javafx list view?

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

I want to increase size of list view items in Java FX. I'm using scene builder, but there is no option to increase font size of list view items.

Comment: How to add css in Java FX scene builder

Comment: You can't add CSS in Scene Builder. Scene Builder just creates the FXML file.

Comment: So how can i add css file to Javafx

Comment: The usual way. It doesn't matter if you use scene builder. Just add your stylesheet to the scene.

Comment: There is an [old SceneBuilder tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/user_guide/stylesheet-support.htm) on how to attach sample CSS stylesheets to an FXML file or preview the FXML with them applied in SceneBuilder, it may be outdated for the current SceneBuilder version, but you could review that to see if it assists you.

Comment: Indeed, there is a "stylesheets" control in scene builder, that appears under "properties" if you have any `Parent` instance selected. Clicking on it lets you choose a CSS file.

Answer (score 3):

You can put

```css
.list-cell {
    -fx-font-size: 1.5em ;
}
```

(for example) in your external CSS file.

You could also just style the list view directly, though inline styles in general are not recommended:

```
listView.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 1.5em ;");
```